# set Background Image and xml Resource

Tags: android, android-xml, repeat

I am using the following below code to round the corners of RelativeLayout. I save this as `mybackground.xml` in `drawable` folder.
It's working fine for rounding the corner but the problem is that I also want to add an transparent image as a background of my RelativeLayout. How can I achieve both things? How can I use an image and a drawable xml (for rounding the corner) at the same time for a RelativeLayout ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
   <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
            android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Layer-List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

It will be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
             android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item><!-- your transparent image --></item>
 </layer-list>
```

Comment: And set this new drawable as background of your RelativeLayout

Answer (score 18):

use Layer List and Item tag for setting Image and use  solid tag and set the color as #AA000000 for transparent as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
      <solid android:color="#AA000000"/>
      <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" 
               android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
               android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/yourfilename"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot its working fine all of above comments guide me .   . . . .

Comment: awesome, i used this method to provide a rounded corner to a fragment.. thanks

Comment: @AmithGC: Thanks for the encouragement and support dude,:)

Answer (score 2):

This one works. If you dont round corners of your pic you will not be able to see rounded corner too. Some friends talked about this in previous answers. They should round their image to see round effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listviewback2">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="35dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="35dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="35dp"
                android:topRightRadius="35dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item> 
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
   <item>
       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background"/>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```