# Best way to create a rounded corener button with a background that has a repeating bitmap.

Tags: android, android-button

I would just like to know the best way to achieve this. I have a button that has rounded corners however I would also like to have the background of the button be a texture that is tiled.

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you matej for your suggestions however they do not work :(. I ended up just doing the inevitable and created a custom view where I imported a GradientDrawable from my resources where I defined the rounded corners etc, and then I also imported my "texture" as a BitmapDrawable and used PorterDuffXfermode to mask it. It would be nice to be able to create a shape and then apply a drawable to that shape :(.

Answer (score 1):

For rounded corners check this:

http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/customize-button-in-android/

to add image background, just add this into dravable resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" 
             android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
             android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/yourfilename" 
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
  </item>
 </layer-list>
```

from: [set Background Image and xml Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609828/set-background-image-and-xml-resource)

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't do anything because the rounded shape is drawn first then the square bitmap on top. so it ends up just being a rectangle.